# Google compute engine static IP can't ping issue

Tags: firewall, ping, google-compute-engine

I use the Google compute engine service and have configured a static IP for the instance.

The firewall uses the defaults open tcp:1-65535, udp:1-65535.

But use localhost can't ping to instance.

It's like a Google compute engine firewall setting issue, but I don't know how to change the settings.

Comment: ICMP could still be blocked. Are you using `ping` from your local computer to access the server? Are you able to connect to other services (say, a TCP service)?

Comment: The ICMP none blocked. I used local computer ping other server ok! but ping my google compute instance no reply, all packet missed.

Comment: Are you sure you unblocked IMCP? Google has instructions here: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#ipaddresses

Try running `gcutil --project=myproject addfirewall icmpfirewall --allowed=icmp # allow ICMP traffic` on your instance.

Comment: Great!!!  your comment are right! the default setting have ICMP but it's internal IP, not allow external access. It need add firewall icmp rule for "0.0.0.0/0", Thank Taj Morton reply.

Answer (score 2):

In cloud console networks panel's "Protocol & Ports" field, you will need to add "icmp" to make it ping-able.

for example: `tcp:80,443;udp:5000-6000;icmp`